How to ignore inferred type errors from jsx files in the tsx files?
I have a TSX file that imports a JSX component in a large code base, sort of like this:
// Foo.tsx

import Bar from 'bar.jsx'

// ...

<Bar
  className="red"
>
  Hello, world!
</Bar>

// ...

and
const Bar = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>
}

When running my application, I get a large amount of compilation errors like:
TS2322: Type '{ children: (string | Element)[]; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'. Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
Unfortunately, its not feasible for me to upgrade all of my jsx components to tsx at this time. So, is there an easy way to configure TS to stop trying to infer types from my unmigrated JSX files and prevent these errors?

add any type to parameters
forwardRef((props:any, ref) => {
return {props.children}
}
